# Which artifact contains android.util.Half?

Tags: android, maven

I'm trying to use `com.android.Half` in my project and I can't find the artifact contains the class in `maven.google.com`.

Which artifact contains the class of `android.util.Half`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't part of an unbundled library, it is part of the Android framework and, as per [the Javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Half), only available on API 26 or higher devices.

Comment: Oh. you mean there is no artifact contains that class and that class only available in device? Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: That's what I said, yup.